# Unable to start the Transact-SQL debugger, could not connect to the database engine instance

Tags: sql, t-sql, debugging

I have been trying to run debugging within SQl server management studio and for some reason the debugger has just stopped working.

This is the message I get:

> Unable to start the Transact-SQL debugger, could not connect to the
> database engine instance 'server-sql'. Make sure you have enabled the
> debugging firewall exceptions and are using a login that is a member
> of the sysadmin fixed server role. The RPC server is unavailable.

Before this I get two messages, one requesting firewall permissions and the next says 'usage' with some text that makes little sense.

I have looked at the other similar answers on there for the same message which suggest adding the login as a sysadmin but that is already set. I also tried adding sysadmin to another account but that also didn't work.

Comment: There is a list of things to check here: http://bit.ly/1pPyQqO

Comment: Ok the answer was in there. It seems I needed to run as admin.

Comment: Are you trying to debug your local SQL instance ? In my case, I use the IP `127.0.0.1` instead of a named instance like `(local)`, and it works.

Comment: it worked for me, when i started Studio as "admin" and connected with "windows authentication" instead of "sa"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the end I was able to start it by right clicking and selecting run as administrator.

Comment: @cahitbeyaz me neither. The only thing that worked was debugging locally, on the server the DB was located on.

Comment: @alex it is working both locally and remotely for me after running SSMS as administrator.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered this issue while connected to SQL using a SQL Server Authenticated user. Once I tried using a Windows Authenticated user I was able to debug without issue. That user must also be assigned the sysadmin role.

Comment: This also solved my problem. I was connecting via SSMS (running as Administrator) as a SQL Server user (which has sysadmin role) and I got the same error as the OP above. Based on jRosenholm's answer here I created a Windows AD user with sysadmin role on the same server and reconnected as that user running SSMS as Administrator and the debugger spun up without error.

Answer (score 2):

I try with the following steps, **but it did not work** (maybe because I'm on a PC in a office and I don't have control of the firewall). But you can try the following.

1. Check the users role:

   ```
   IF IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('sysadmin') = 1
   print 'Current user''s login is a member of the sysadmin role'
   ```
2. Follow these instructions:
   [configure the transact-SQL Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646024.aspx)
3. Run SQL Server Management Standard Edition 64 bits (with SQL Server Account)

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me and I could not find the resolution anywhere.  My firewall is disabled so I knew that couldn't be the issue.

According to [Microsoft: Configure firewall rules before running the TSQL Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/configure-firewall-rules-before-running-the-tsql-debugger):

> The server needs to communicate back to the client via RPC. The
>   account under which SQL Server service is running should have
>   authenticate permissions to the client.

We had a group policy that was preventing this:

> Deny access to this computer from the network (Local account, Guests)

In order to resolve the issue, I had to add the SQL Server service account to the local group "Remote Desktop Users" on my desktop.  Hope this helps someone else resolve this frustrating issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I received this error message:

> Unable to start the Transact-SQL debugger, could not connect to the computer "local".

I end up close the existing connection, then reconnect to my local SQL server using IP 127.0.0.1 and it works.

Answer (score 1):

What helped me, was from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646024(v=sql.100).aspx):

> SQL Server Management Studio must be running under a Windows account that is a member of the sysadmin fixed server roll.
>
> The Database Engine Query Editor window must be connected by using
>   either a Windows Authentication or SQL Server Authentication login
>   that is a member of the sysadmin fixed server role.

So, I've added sysadmin role to my windows account and run ssms as administrator. Debugger started working normally.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to above works, what make our 2 computers remote debug able, was running: (right click on Window's Start button)

System--> Advanced System Properties-->Computer Name-->Click on **Network ID...** button

and running that wizard to join workgroup on both computers.
I found this solution by looking at my Windows' Event Viewer and looking for a solution to errors with NetBT Source, that is related to workgroup and computer Name.
Update: after some days, it stop working again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and double checked al recommended settings. At some point I disabled the firewall on the database server and it worked like a charm. By enabling and checking the Firewall log I noticed this entry:

2019-10-31 16:07:50 DROP **TCP** 192.168.xxx.xxx 192.168.xxx.xxx 65231 **61214** 52 S 56576751 0 8192 - - - RECEIVE

When I allowed TCP port 61214 (Inbound rule) and switched the firewall back on, it worked. I don't know why this port is needed, maybe some here on SO?

Anyway, maybe the firewall log can be of help too.

Answer (score 0):

Struggled through many hours and got the answer
You can do the configuration through this doc
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/configure-firewall-rules-before-running-the-tsql-debugger?view=sql-server-ver15
(1) 2 settings need  to done on the remote server where Sql server is installed
(2) 1 setting at client computer (i.e) our computer