# Problem trying to debug procedure on SSMS 2016

Tags: ssms, ssms-2016

I am trying to debug a procedure on SQL Server 2016, but without success. I asked the support team about permissions and they said that my user has all the permissions. Here I attach some prints about the messages being displayed by SSMS. HResult E_FAIL Error.

[Print 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTBLB.png) [Print 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5xOU.png) [Print 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9asve.png)

Comment: Your prints weren't attached. Also, you could describe exactly what you're doing to debug this procedure. Here's an example from MS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-debug-stored-procedures?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: My bad, I´ve edited and attached the prints. I am just selecting the procedure through the editor and calling debug button. It used to work before. I think something behind infra changed, like firewall, proxy, network, etc, that is forbidding my access. I already tried to talk with the infra team and they don´t know what is.

Comment: Have you tried any of these?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491024/unable-to-start-the-transact-sql-debugger-could-not-connect-to-the-database-eng

Comment: I got it disabling firewall on database server! Thank you very much!